# Communicate from Watch to killed iOS app using WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2

Using WatchOS2 and `WatchConnectivity`, is it possible to 'wake up' the iOS counterpart to send it a message using 'interactive messaging'?

The reason I ask is because I have a WatchOS1 app that is using `openParentApplication` to send/receive messages which actually wakes up the iOS app if it was not running, makes it receive my message and lets it send back a response. After that it closes down the iOS app again.

I am a bit confused as how to do the same kind of thing in WatchOS2. Because when I use 'interactive messaging' using `WCSession` the message I send is not delivered when I kill the iOS app.

I also noticed WatchOS2 now contains all sorts of frameworks you can use, like `NSURLSession` and `EventKit` which delegates all calls to the iPhone. So maybe that is the recommended way to go? My watch-app coincidentally only requires events from `EventKit` to operate. So I could rewrite the `WatchConnectivity` part of my app to use `EventKit` instead. And if my app would have to use HTTP, I could use `NSURLSession` directly.

Can anybody confirm that the intended way to communicate with the iPhone now in WatchOS2 is to use
 native frameworks like `CoreData`/`EventKit`/etc? It makes sense if it is, but I do like to have someone confirm this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure to set up the WCSession in a part of your iOS app that gets run when the iOS app is running in the background (`UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would be one of these spots, while any UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` would not be one of those)

Comment: Actually I had my WCSession activation in a `didBecomeActive` callback, which also isn't called when woken up in the background!

Comment: Tom van Zummeren I too having same issue, sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler is not waking up inactive iOS App in background. gettign 7001 error. i have activated sessions in both App delegate Lunch methods.

Comment: That does not sound like the same issue. If you want help you should ask a new SO question

Answer (score 5):

`WCSession` is the recommended way of communicating between the watch and iOS device.

For immediate communication use `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` method of the `WCSession` instance. As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:):

> Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active
>   and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background
>   and makes it reachable.

In cases when the other device can't be reached, e.g. because it's out of range, you may want to use `updateApplicationContext:error:` method instead. It will queue the data and deliver it later to the counterpart device.

Comment: Yes, this is the 'interactive messaging' I was referring to. And it just doesn't work when the iOS app is not running. In Xcode 7, when I call `sendMessage` from the WatchKit extension when the iOS app is killed, the message never arrives. As soon as I start the iOS app, the message suddenly gets delivered and sends back a reply. So what it says in the documentation simply does not happen in reality. Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: I just tested it again; it does not work on either Simulator or device. It works fine until you kill the app, then messages are not delivered anymore until you open the app again.

Comment: I ran a small test and I received replies from `sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)`, even after killing the app on the phone. Are you using the final release of Watch OS2, from 2 days ago? Beta versions had numerous connectivity bugs.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. Maybe I should try reinstalling my watch and phone then! I installed the GM version and even the small update (~50mb) that came after that.

Comment: Still does not work... what am I doing wrong? Did you configure any special background modes?

Comment: I ran my test case many times more and in fact there seems to be a problem with re-instantiating the iOS app in the background after it was killed. While I did get a response 2-3 times, most of the time I didn't. So it seems to be a bug in the current version of WatchOS.

Comment: Now that I got it working using ccjensen's solution, I also sometimes still don't get a reply. That's a bummer.

Comment: It still doesn't work in iOS 10.3. App on the iPhone just don't get started.